# simple exercise of subclass in Scala

Tags: scala, subclass, extends

I have a simple doubt about Scala and subclass.

I have these classes:

```
class A {
  def hello() = println("hello from A")
}

class B extends A {
  override def hello() = println("hello from B")
}

class C extends A {
  override def hello() = println("hello from C")
}
```

Now, in the three class there is a method called "hello()"

I have the object: `c:C`

And I perform: `a:A = c`

How can now call the method "hello()" of C through the object a?

Comment: Since your reference a:A already referring to object c:C so a.hello or c.hello is similar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `C` instance hello method is getting called.

## Scala REPL

```
scala> class A {
     |   def hello() = println("hello from A")
     | }
defined class A

scala>

scala> class B extends A {
     |   override def hello() = println("hello from B")
     | }
defined class B

scala>

scala> class C extends A {
     |   override def hello() = println("hello from C")
     | }
defined class C

scala> val a: A = new C
a: A = C@764fffa0


scala> a.hello
hello from C
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a `type` and a `class`. When you say

```
class A {...}
```

You define both a type `A` and a class `A`. When you say

```
class B extends A {...}
```

You define a new class `B` with a type `B`. But crucially, the type of `B` is a subtype of the type of `A` so you can use a value of type `B` where ever you can use a value of type `A`.

When you say

```
val b = new B
```

You create a new instance of the class `B` and put the reference in `b`. The type of `b` is the type of `B`.

When you say

```
val a: A = b
```

You make `a` a reference to the same instance of class `B` but you tell it to treat it as if its type was the type of `A`. This is OK because `B` is a subclass of `A` and subclasses inherit the type of their parent.

Since `a` refers to an instance of `B`, when you call the `hello` method like this

```
a.hello()
```

It will call the `hello` method defined for a object of class `B`, because that is what is held in `a`.

So even though the *type* of `a` is `A`, the *value* it refers to is actually of type `B` because it is an instance of class `B`. In your example there is another level of inheritance, but the same principle applies: You can assign an instance of class `C` to a reference of type `A`, but it will still be an instance of class `C` and with have the `hello` method from class `C`, not the one from class `A`.